# Как спарсить данные после определенного текста Python Selenium bs4

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, bs4

На одном из сайтов, для которого пишу парсер, столкнулся с такой проблеммой:
Нужно взять все данные из таблицы, но они не подписаны в html коде и меняются местами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама таблица на сайте выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала я использовал XPATH для этого, но при парсинге обнаружил, что некоторрые данные меняются местами, например двигатель и регистрационный номер, или вообще отсутсвуют.
Так что XPATH не подходит, ибо в csv файл в строку с двигателем может попасть данные с пробегом

Можно как то в селениуме или через bs4 сначала искать слово, а потом парсить данные после него?

То есть, что бы он находил в html коде слово Engine, а затем брал данные ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как по мне, легче получить через requests весь код сайта и вырезать нужный участок с данными, после чего искать нужное слово, отступать 2 символа и брать цифру. Дайте ссылку на сайт.

Comment: @Utsiye я через селениум получаю весь html сайта и так, а дальше работаю через bs4 c ним, просто через запросы даже с усер агентами он отдает не праавильный код
https://www.nettiauto.com/en/ford/f150/11869397

Comment: Я тоже писал парсера, но по моему опыт, если получается, то лучше вручную искать, так у вас больше возможностей.